# Why is my data extension not being updated?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have a subscriber and I want to update their surname. CloudPages processes this, but I do not see an update in my data extension.

This is my code:

```
    %%[

if RequestParameter("submitted") == false then

*/ these variables are used to hold the form data */

var @firstname,@surname,@email
SET @firstname = RequestParameter("First Name")
SET @surname = RequestParameter("Surname")
SET @email = RequestParameter("Email Address")

elseif RequestParameter("submitted") == true then

UpdateData('AudienceOne',1,'Email Address',@email,'Surname',@surname)

endif

]%%

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      %%[ if RequestParameter("submitted") == true then ]%%

  <p>Thank you for submitting your details.</p>
    
      %%[ else ]%%

      <h2>Register</h2>
      <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
         <label>First name</label><br><br>
         <input type="text" name="firstname"><br><br>
         <label>Last name</label><br><br>
         <input type="text" name="lastname"><br><br>
        <label>Email</label><br><br>
         <input type="text" name="email">
         <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true" /><br><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
      </form>

      %%[ endif ]%%

   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `submitted` variable doesn't have a value on page load, but you're checking it for `false`.  I'd just drop that part completely:

```ampscript
%%[

   /* set var values from send context */
   set @firstname = AttributeValue("First Name")
   set @surname = AttributeValue("Surname")
   set @email = AttributeValue("Email Address")

   if RequestParameter("submitted") == "true" then

      /* set var values upon form post */
      set @firstname = RequestParameter("firstname")
      set @surname = RequestParameter("lastname")
      set @email = RequestParameter("email")

      UpdateData('AudienceOne',1,'Email Address', @email,'Surname', @surname)

   endif

]%%
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      
      %%[ if RequestParameter("submitted") == "true" then ]%%

         <p>Thank you for submitting your details.</p>
    
      %%[ else ]%%

         <h2>Register</h2>
         <form action="%%=RequestParameter('PAGEURL')=%%" method="post">
            <label>First name</label><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="firstname" value="%%=v(@firstname)=%%"><br><br>
            <label>Last name</label><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" value="%%=v(@surname)=%%"><br><br>
            <label>Email</label><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="email" value="%%=v(@email)=%%">
            <input name="submitted" type="hidden" value="true" /><br><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
         </form>

      %%[ endif ]%%

   </body>
</html>
```

Also, you can default the values from your form from the email send context using the [AttributeValue](https://ampscript.guide/attributevalue) function.